# Cannot unpack array with string keys

Tags: php, arrays, argument-unpacking

The error message is:

> FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Cannot unpack array with string keys

I know I can simply run the method `fetch()` twice and pass the `['q']` and `['bind']`, but I am trying to get to grips with using the new `...` to unpack values. I want to pass the values like so:

```
(string) SQL, (Array) Bind Values
```

But I think it tries to unpack the bind values array as well as the response array from the `fetch()` method. Is it possible to unpack this array?

It looks something like this:

```
array(2) {
    ["q"] => string(7) "example"
    ["bind"] => array(1) {
        ["example"] => string(3) "one"
    }
}
```

This is the whole code, in case you need to see how it all fits together:

```
class ModelController {
    public static function execute($sql, $vals) {
        var_dump($vals);
    }
}

class ModelContainer {

    private $queries = [];

    public function add_model(Model $model, $name) {
        $this->queries[$name] = $model;
        return $this;
    }

    public function exec_all() {
        foreach($this->queries as $q) {
            ModelController::execute(...$q->fetch());
        }
    }

    public function exec($name) {

    }

}

class Model {

    private $sql;
    private $vals = [];


    public function set_q($statement) {
        $this->sql = $statement;
        return $this;
    }

    public function bind($vals = []) {
        $this->vals = $vals;
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch() {
        return ['q' => (string)$this->sql,
            'bind' => $this->vals ];
    }
}

$m = new ModelContainer();
$m->add_model((new Model)->set_q('example SQL content here')->bind(['example' => 'example value here']), 'one');
$m->exec_all();
```

Comment: Do a `$values = array_values($q->fetch()); ModelController::execute(...$values)`

Comment: That completely worked! Could you provide an answer to what `array_values()` does in this situation in relation to unpacking? It would be appreciated @apokryfos

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The problem is that the [splat operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (array unpacking operator or `...`) does not work with associative arrays. Example:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$assoc = ["one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3];

var_dump(...$array); //Works
var_dump(...$assoc); //Doesn't work
```

You need to force an array to be numerically indexed in order to unpack it. You do this using [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$values = array_values($q->fetch());
ModelController::execute(...$values);
```

Array values will ensure all values have a sequential numeric key.

**Update**

Starting PHP 8 there will be support for named arguments which will make both cases work. This will make calling a function using the array unpacking operator and an associative array work, as long as the array keys match the argument names. An example is documented in the [proposed RFC for named arguments](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params#variadic_functions_and_argument_unpacking) which says the following code should work starting PHP 8.

```
$params = ['start_index' => 0, 'num' => 100, 'value' => 50];
array_fill(...$params);
```

Comment: This completely ruins the principle of using associative arrays, the key/index was going to be used as the SQL placeholder match so maybe its a limitation to what I need? Thanks a lot for the explanation! I'll mark when I can

Comment: I'd expect it to be a limitation on how functions work with their arguments lists, e.g. `func_get_args()` is always numerically indexed.

Comment: Look's like it is back to the drawing board then haha, appreciated this knowledge however!

Comment: If you are expecting to pass an associative array to a function in this manner, rewrite your method to take an array: `function execute(array $arguments) { var_dump($array['vals']); }`

Comment: Support for named arguments will come in PHP 8.1. It's not available in PHP 8.0. Source: https://www.amitmerchant.com/array-unpacking-with-string-keys-coming-in-php-81/

Comment: @Boschman that link talks about array unpacking with string keys. Named argument support has already hit 8.0 as seen [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/973b885e14615d6cf1c8e4d371b4b93af20a9210)

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I misunderstood. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Well you could also use `...(array_values($params))` if for a function or just use `call_user_func_array` https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: another interesting behaviour is, unpacking assocArray into a php8 function uses the keys as named parameters and will still break if the function parms do not match the array keys.

Answer (score 33):

### Update PHP 8.1

Since PHP 8.1, unpacking arrays also works with string-key arrays, so the error *FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Cannot unpack array with string keys* will not be applicable anymore.

Example:

```
$array1 = ["a" => 1];
$array2 = ["a" => 2];
$array = ["a" => 0, ...$array1, ...$array2];
var_dump($array); // ["a" => 2]
```

RFC: *[PHP RFC: Array unpacking with string keys](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_unpacking_string_keys)*

Answer (score 20):

If you got this error when you tried to unpack an associative array into another array then you can use `array_merge` instead:

```php
<?php

$inner = ["b" => "i", "c" => "i"];
$outer = ["a" => "o", "c" => "o"];

var_dump(array_merge($outer, $inner));
var_dump(array_merge($inner, $outer));
```

will produce

```
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "o"
  ["c"]=>
  string(1) "i"
  ["b"]=>
  string(1) "i"
}

array(3) {
  ["b"]=>
  string(1) "i"
  ["c"]=>
  string(1) "o"
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "o"
}
```